# Is there a way to programmatically upgrade dependency version in pom.xml using java

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, pom.xml

I'm doing a project on Java dependency upgrade solution. For that i want to edit the pom.xml programmatically and upgrade the dependency version on pom.xml file. I came across a library called aether for dependency handling but it lacks documentation. or else can i do it by open pom.xml as a file and update the version of the dependency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look into using [Maven Versions Plugin](https://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/)

> The Versions Plugin is used when you want to manage the versions of
>   artifacts in a project's POM.

Specifically with its way of [advancing dependency versions](https://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/examples/advancing-dependency-versions.html).

Comment: Can this plugin be programmatically used to manage dependencies version?

Comment: I came across Maven Version Plugin but does it can be use to programatically use in Java

Comment: @EugenCovaci Depends on how do you define programmatically. You can use command line using java as well though. We've been using it via shell scripts to perform an auto upgrade of dependency versions.

Comment: Actually  [maven-invoker](http://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-invoker/usage.html) along with Maven Versions Plugin  does the job.